# Block outgoing connection (an IP address) in c#

Tags: c#, ip, block

I would like to block an IP from c#.

I looked up MSDN, and found only firewall exception usage.

Is there any other simpler solutions? I don't want to touch my client's computer setting.

Comment: How do you mean? You can instruct the OS to prevent connections, but as you noted that changes the setting. A lowly application has no authority to refuse connections at the kernel level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, only the OS or an application that hooks into the OS can block outgoing connections. The firewall is the best place to do this.

Comment: // Thanks. I think I might need to make an option to remove setting in that case.